# lslogins Frozen and not Responding

Tags: command-line, rhel, freeze

I have two RHEL 7 systems and one is able to run `lslogins`, but the other one will run it, but freezes and doesn't finish.
The `$PATH` variable has the required variables and matches the other system.

```
#echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

#whereis lslogins
lslogins: /usr/bin/lslogins /usr/share/man/man1/lslogins.1.gz

#ls -l /usr/bin/lslogins
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 54152 Oct 29 05:14 /usr/bin/lslogins
```

The hash of the file on both systems are identical.

What else should I check to try and identify the problem.  I am not seeing any obvious differences between the two systems.  Thanks.

Comment: Confirm whether any of the of the following also hang: ``w
who
users
last -ap now
lastlog``

Comment: All of those commands work.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the problem was winbind. Winbind was active and lslogins was attempting to inquire into active directory.  As soon as winbind was disabled, it was able to immediately pull all local account information.